# C++ : Point address of variable to address of pointer struct member

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

For simplifying some code, I am trying to assign the address of a boolean to address of a member of a structure.

```
struct test{
     boolean outputs[32];
     boolean inputs[32]'
}

test_hardware * machine;

boolean * out_start_machine = &machine.outputs[0];
```

this way I could have *out_startmachine = TRUE, and then use machine.outputs in another area of my code in a more convenient way.

But this is not compiling/working correctly. I am misunderstanding how to get the address out of the pointer struct. Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: `machine` is a pointer (`test_hardware* machine`) but you're using `machine.outputs` instead of `machine->outputs`, also the code shown doesn't initialize the `machine` pointer to a meaningful value.

Comment: 'But this is not compiling/working correctly" - this is not a useful thing to say here. Did it compile or not, if not what was the compiler message. If it did comile what was the bad runtime behavior? Did it run but produce wrong results, did it crash, if so how,... @dasblinkenlight already has the solution for this one, so just for future SO questions

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.

This does compile. The issue I am having is that this code is not working correctly. When I assign a value to *out_startmachine, the value of machine.outputs[0] does not change.

Comment: LOL - this code does not compile, or even close, When I fix the dumb errors i get the complaint that you are using '.' instead of '->' as people have already pointed out. prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:12:37: error: request for member ‘outputs’ in ‘machine’, which is of pointer type ‘test_hardware*’ (maybe you meant to use ‘->’ ?)
 bool * out_start_machine = &machine.outputs[0];

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you want.

```
struct test {
    bool outputs[32];
    bool inputs[32];
};




int main()
{

    test machine;

    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        machine.outputs[i] = false;
    }

    bool * out_start_machine = &machine.outputs[0];
    *out_start_machine = true;


    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        std::cout << machine.outputs[i] << "\n";
    }

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```